# PostgreSQL Generate create Foreign keys from information_schema or pg_constraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, dump

Recently on a testing infrastructure, to restore multiple tables (via `copy` command) I dropped all the foreign keys.
I have restored this database schema dump into a different database before dropping the FK.

Is there any way that I can generate the create FK from `information_schema` or `pg_constraint`?

I tried to get it from a dump file, but the `create table` statement itself having the FK (not an Alter table statement).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `pg_constraint_def`, like in the following example:

```
SELECT pg_get_constraintdef(oid)
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE conname = 'child_accountid_itemid_fkey';
```

Comment: I think it gives a better idea, let me try.